# Android Studio Project disappeared

Tags: android, project, android-studio, auto-update, file-recovery

I just did an update of Android Studio and the project I was working currently on was completely erased. I think it prompt me on "terminating the main process" and I accidentally clicked ok. Is there a way to recover my project somehow? Why would the files be erased by simply updating?

Comment: There is no way that Studio "erased" your project.  You know where it is stored on disk?  Just use a file explorer to browse that location.  It's possible that the project files have been corrupted but you can recover that by reimporting the code.

Comment: I know where Android Studio stores the projects within the file system. It is just gone, nowhere to be found. I even used file recovery tools but nothing came up.

Comment: it never happen,cuz studio always ask to reload project after updating.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049250/recover-file-in-android-studio

Answer (score 3):

In my case i didnt lose the whole project just the main folder which contains the java and the ressource file 
I right click the project --> local history --> show history 
--> revert selection
If you dont have the project you can create one with the same name same  file names then do exactly the same thing  as mentioned
Its a lesson to  use github   :v

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same situation. I haven't been able to replicate the behaviour. My hope is the details bellow will contribute to some answer.

I was working on a project that required the addition of some JAR dependancies. The JAR dependancies, were added to the lib file and I was editing the project build.gradle script to compile them.

I was adding a dependency for jackson JSON to the build.gradle file when the issue occurred.

While typing 'compile com' android studio locked up for a moment. All the files in the project manger disappeared. Android Studio ran thru a gradle build.

Initially I though I'd inadvertently opened an new empty project. Unfortunately my files were gone.

1. Android Studio Never Closed or Crashed
2. The Folder which contained all the project files was completely empty. As if a batch deletion had occurred.
3. 'File -> Open Recent' showed no evidence that the given project had been opened.

I had been working on this file during the previous 24 hours, opening it thru the 'File -> Open Recent' that morning to pick up where I left off the previous day.

It was Disconcerting.

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Comment: You must have 50 reputation to comment. Better this than no information.

Comment: Does answering questions have any prerequisites too?!

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from [the same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386878/android-studio-2-1-1-fully-up-to-date-ide-just-crashed-and-my-project-files-d/37388166#37388166?newreg=6227696d40c64626ad262a83ad994d58).

The project is not erased,just moved to another place, I also don't know why.

I just search my project's name in all my disk, then find the project under another folder.

I use the Mac OS, so the new folder is-

```
/Users/jokerlee/Applications/AndroidStudioProjects
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14314924)

Comment: Got it, i just answer the question first time.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the Same problem even now on Android Studio  3.1.4.
The entire project folder is wiped out.

But what I do currently is immediately save the entire project folder somewhere, like Company Folder, then Copy and paste again. Hectic though.

Done this ten times now. I will test not using default project location like /users/........

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem too. I solved the problem by doing following steps.

1. In Android Studio, open the **project main directory**.

   **File** -> **Open** -> **Folder** path where your missing project existed.

   Lets say if your missing project is under ..**/AndroidStudioPrj/MyApp**, please open **AndroidStudioPrj** directory.
2. **Then VCS -> Local History -> Show History**
   In history, you can revert to get back your code.
   [[image: VCS->Local History->Show1]

Answer (score 0):

I created an API module just in line with the app module. But when I closed Android Studio and then opened it again, the file was no longer visible in the Android Studio project and Android View.

Then I reinstalled Android Studio and cleared the caches and local history, and it worked for me. I got that module back in place.

For clearing caches and local history :-
Go to -> File -> Invalidate caches.
Tick all the parameters and click "Invalidate and Restart" button.