# Recover file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a project in Android Studio (Version 1.2) and after working on that project for a few weeks, my PC suddenly shut down (Android Studio was open at that time).

After starting the PC again, I found that one of my files was completely erased.

Here is the snapshot of the workspace -

[image: my workspace]

As you can see, nothing is left on that file.

Is there any way to recover that file? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: can you check if something in the local history of the file?

Comment: I recommend using a VCS such as git after encountering this. Besides, it encourage you to quantize your work into separate small stages (i.e commits)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55649428/3496570

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Can you find the file in file explorer?**

If you can, try to open the file through another explorer

You can find your projects path by right clicking the project and hitting "File Path"

**Is there local history available?**

Try right clicking the faulty file and checking *Local History* -> *Show History*

If you can fetch the local history, right click the history entry and click *revert*

Comment: There's no local history available either?

Comment: I am just curious to know whether it is possible to fetch a file if local history is not available too?

Comment: If the file isn't available in Android Studio I would try a file recovery solution, but unfortunately as Windows user I can't suggest any but Google might give you results

Answer (score 26):

you can go to **VCS>Local History>show History** 
and find from which Hour/minute you want to revert and hit revert. 
I've done this before and it saved my life.

Comment: My heart is still pounding from having almost lost 4 days of nonstop work.  "Thank you" does not even begin to express the gratitude I have for this.

Comment: wow. Just recovered accidentally deleted package. Saved my life , thanks .

Answer (score 12):

If the file is not exists anymore, create a new file with the exact same name then try to use VCS-> Local History-> show History.

This was the only way works for me for a new file that was saved correctly/deleted.

Comment: seems just a /little/ bit like voodoo!  Wasn't in git, stash changes, or the filesystem...but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another day, Android studio saved my days of hardwork when I accidentally deleted an entire project files (note: the root folder of the project was available). There were no files left to search for local history. Steps I followed as below.

Opened the root project in Android studio.
[image]

And right click on the parent folder, from which is empty currently -> choose 'Local history' -> 'show history'.

This will show all the deleted files as 'External change' , now you can revert back to the entry before the history item marked as 'External change'. This will revert back all the 'Shift + deleted' files!

After recovery I can still see some files which are missing recent changes, which can obviously be recovered using the same process for individual files.

Now I was able to recover an entire android studio project which was 'shift+deleted'. This is a priceless moment for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you had already imported the project from VCS but accidentally removed the `.vcs` file and lost your files while cleaning your project or *unrevisioned* files. Just go to 
 **Preferences -> Version Control (for mac)** or **Settings -> Version Control (for windows)** 
 and we will be seeing a `directory` with `VCS` status. By selecting and applying the changes, the project automatically syncs and is updated with your previous from. Find the attached image for reference. 
You can also just enable the VCS from your toolbar and sync the project. 
Thanks

> N:B: I couldn't find the VCS -> Local History initially because I
> was needed to enable the VCS first. [Check my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969720/how-to-recover-local-uncommited-files-that-accidentally-got-deleted-in-android-s/70969721#70969721)

[image]