# Recover the deleted project android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-recovery, delete-directory

```
 I have a problem. I accidentally deleted the project folder.
```

Can i recover codes of some java? Is there a way for it? 
 Maybe local history or another way...

Comment: Did you check on the checkbox, **delete contents on the disk also**?

Comment: Windows might have kept a previous version. Possibly.

Comment: @UmaKanth deleted folder on the disk.  and cant see project on android studio now

Comment: in case the root folder is available and all the files in the project are 'shift+deleted' , try out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63424377/4374362)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to retrieve your project by getting back your files on the disk. Try the software [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) (same company than CCleaner) it did save one of my project recently