# Accidentally deleted entire android studio project folder

Tags: android-studio, recovery

I accidentally deleted my android studio project folder and i dont know how to retrieve it. I tried restoring it from my trash but i only recover the folder without anything inside. Please help me :( Im using lubuntu. Is there any way to recover it ? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877357/recover-the-deleted-project-android-studio   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736733/eclipse-project-was-deleted-how-to-undo-it-or-recover-it

Comment: Thanks for this @Iroshan Vithanage. I used photorec to recover my files. My next problem is, i it recovers all my deleted files is there easier way to look for those files included in my project ?

Answer (score 10):

Create a new project with same name, same package name and try to create new files with same name. After that right click the project folder and select `Local History` → `Show History`. This will help you.