# Recover source code of app installed on Android emulator (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, apk, extract, emulation

My problem is that I finished an app with flutter and it was all ok but I deleted by mistake the flutter projects folder with the whole project inside. And the only thing I have is the app already installed in debug mode inside my android emulator.

Is possible to recover or to extract the source code from the emulator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer is No, Long answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/44821362/10844401

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover file in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049250/recover-file-in-android-studio)