# In android studio how do I reload code files from disk?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, flutter

I am working on a flutter project in android studio. By mistake I run (git clean -xfd)
(git stash save --keep-index)
these command and my all edited file are rollbacked. My all today work is lost. Is there any way to undo or reload a file's contents from disk.
Please Help me...

I tried this but not helping me
[Recover file in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049250/recover-file-in-android-studio)

Comment: Nothing in the local history?

Comment: No, Only one file that is new added by today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto git terminal and hit the following command:

```
$ git stash show
```

Now check if you have anything kept in stash then you are lucky and hit the next command as

```
$ git stash apply
```