# How to recover local uncommited files that accidentally got deleted in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control, file-recovery

I faced a sudden issue, I have deleted some of my un revisioned files during commit to my android project but I found all of the **modified and newly added files were missing** from my `commit` (which I was going to make). I can not just remove or `pull` again the project from the `origin` because it will completely remove the VCS cache of the previous one. How do I get my files back?

I have also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049250/recover-file-in-android-studio) questions and answers but this didn't solve my issue. So, I have found a solution otherwise with new Android Studio update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had already imported the project from VCS but accidentally removed the `.vcs` file and lost your files while cleaning your project or *unrevisioned* files. Just go to 
 **Preferences -> Version Control (for mac)** or **Settings -> Version Control (for windows)** 
 and we will be seeing a `directory` with `VCS` status. By selecting and applying the changes, the project automatically syncs and is updated with your previous from. Find the attached image for reference. 
You can also just enable the VCS from your toolbar and sync the project. 
Thanks

> N:B: I couldn't find the VCS -> Local History initially because I
> was needed to enable the VCS first.

[image]