# Android Studio 2.1.1, fully up-to-date, IDE just crashed, and my project files disappeared

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, ide

So, the IDE crashed, prompted me to "Send a Crash Report" then closed. When I reopened my project, no files were visible. I checked the project folder and there's nothing there, only the .idea folder. All gone! Undelete tools find nothing... A day's work gone!

I've searched this group but found nothing helpful...

Is there a solution to this? Where are my files?

And why would an IDE crash wipe my files?

Comment: If you lost project inside AndroidStudioProject folder then you can make use of EaseUS recovery tool

Comment: @akhil Rao, I had already tried Glary Undelete,nothing found, and was in the middle of doing a deep scan using Recuva when I solved my problem.

The fact the files were 'moved' rather than deleted would explain the failure of recovery tools to find them....

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around on my Hard Drive I noticed that said missing files were in a different project folder - the WRONG folder...

It appears the location of the original project that I copied then refactored was the target for Android Studio to dump the files when it crashed... Consequently the original project files were replaced/over-written...

What I do not understand is that there is are absolutely NO references, nada, to the original project folder in any of the files...

Good news is I got my files back and my project is back on track!

I guess my advice to others in this situation is to check all potentially related project folders for anything that has 'gone missing'.